# Transform Javascript grouped data into JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

Using below code, I am able to group objects from my existing data with Underscore JS as shown.

```
{Group1: Array[10], Group2: Array[13], Group3: Array[16], Group4: Array[21], Group5: Array[38]}


//Create a category based on group assigned
var groupedData = _.groupBy(results, function (d) { 

return d.groups;

});

console.log(groupedData);
```

But what I really need is to turn the above into JSON array looking like:

```
var myData = [["Group1", 10], ["Group2",13], ["Group3",16], ["Group4",21], ["Group5",38]];
```

How can I adjust my code in order to get the desired result?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var results = {
  a: [1, 2],
  b: [2, 3]
};
var grouped = Object.keys(results).map(function(key) {
  return [key, results[key].length];
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(grouped);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Juan, this answers my question.